# Nodejs is not handling data from form input back in the database for user registration

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i am quite new to react and had few issues with javascript. I had created a multi step form and had created a backdend using nodejs. So the idea was to store all the data into a variable and then send it to the server to handle the request by registering the user. but when i click the submit button, the front end is not storing the data in the variable that i created.
Kindly check into my code.

```
 const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: "",
    country: "",
    countryCode: "",
    phone: "",
    otp:"",
    firstname: "",
    middlename:"",
    lastname:"",
    dob:"",
    occupation:"",
    resCountry:"",
    homeaddress:"",
    city:"",
    state:"",
    postalcode:"",

  });

  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  const history = useHistory()

  const nextStep = () => {
    if (step < 7) {
      setStep(step + 1);
    } else if(step === 7) {
        console.log(values);
        history.push("./routes/signup")

    }
  };

  const prevStep = () => {
    if (step > 1) {
      setStep(step - 1);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (name) => (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: e.target.values });
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/signup', handleChange)
      .then(response => console.log(response.data))

    window.location = "../Login"

  };
```

this is the full code.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./MainRegistrationForm.css"
import {Alert, Form,  FormControl, FormGroup, FormLabel, Row, Col} from "react-bootstrap"
import CountrySelect from 'react-bootstrap-country-select';
import 'react-bootstrap-country-select/dist/react-bootstrap-country-select.css';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import AppBar from "../AppBar"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios"

export default function MainRegistrationForm() {
  const Step1 =()=>{
    return (
      <div className="Registration_Form">
          <div className="text-center pb-4">
            <h3>Create your <span style={{color:"#6246EA"}}>ViniPay</span> account</h3>
          </div>
          
          <Form>
              <FormGroup>
                <FormLabel>First, Enter your email address</FormLabel>
                <FormControl 
                type="email"
                name="email"
                required/>
                
                <div className="text-center pt-2">
                  <p className="text-Muted">By registering, you accept our Terms of use and Privacy Policy.</p>
                  
                </div>
              </FormGroup>
          </Form>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const Step2 =()=>{
      const [ value, setValue ] = useState("in"); 
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Registration_Form">
          <div className="text-center pb-4">
            <h3>Your conntry of primary residence</h3>
          </div>
        
          <Form>
              <FormGroup>
                <FormLabel>Select Country</FormLabel>
                  <CountrySelect
                    value={value}
                    onChange={setValue}
                    className='countryselect'
                    name = "country"              /> 
              </FormGroup>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const Step3 =()=>{
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div className="Registration_Form">
            <div className="text-center pb-4">
              <h3>Verify your phone number with OTP</h3>
            </div>
          
            <Form>
                <FormGroup>
                  <FormLabel>Enter your phone number</FormLabel>
                  <Row>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                      <div className=''>
                      <div className="input-group">
                            <div className="">
                              <Form.Select className="currency-selector mb-2" aria-label="Country Code" name="countryCode">              
                              <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India (+91)</option>
                              <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">USA (+1)</option>
                              <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK (+44)</option>
                              <optgroup label="Other countries">
                                <option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="AO" value="244">Angola (+244)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="AI" value="1264">Anguilla (+1264)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="AG" value="1268">Antigua &amp; Barbuda (+1268)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="AR" value="54">Argentina (+54)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="AM" value="374">Armenia (+374)
                                <option data-countryCode="TG" value="228">Togo (+228)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="TO" value="676">Tonga (+676)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="TT" value="1868">Trinidad &amp; Tobago (+1868)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="TN" value="216">Tunisia (+216)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="TR" value="90">Turkey (+90)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="TM" value="7">Turkmenistan (+7)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="TM" value="993">Turkmenistan (+993)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="TC" value="1649">Turks &amp; Caicos Islands (+1649)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="TV" value="688">Tuvalu (+688)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="UG" value="256">Uganda (+256)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="UA" value="380">Ukraine (+380)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="AE" value="971">United Arab Emirates (+971)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="UZ" value="7">Uzbekistan (+7)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="VU" value="678">Vanuatu (+678)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="VA" value="379">Vatican City (+379)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="VE" value="58">Venezuela (+58)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="VN" value="84">Vietnam (+84)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="VG" value="84">Virgin Islands - British (+1284)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="VI" value="84">Virgin Islands - US (+1340)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="WF" value="681">Wallis &amp; Futuna (+681)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="YE" value="969">Yemen (North)(+969)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="YE" value="967">Yemen (South)(+967)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="ZM" value="260">Zambia (+260)</option>
                                <option data-countryCode="ZW" value="263">Zimbabwe (+263)</option>
                              </optgroup>
                              </Form.Select>
                            </div>
                            
                      </div>
                    </div>          
                    </Col>

                    <Col sm={8}>
                      <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="tel" placeholder="Your phone  number ..." name="phone" />
                    </Col>
                    <div className="text-center">
                      <p className="text-Muted" 
                        style={{fontSize:"14px"}}
                        >Please select the right county code, It Helps to keep your account safe. 
                        <span style={{color:"#6246EA"}}>Learn More</span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </Row>
                </FormGroup>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const Step4 =()=>{
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Registration_Form">
          <div className="text-center pb-4">
            <h3>Enter Your OTP</h3>
            <p>OTP sent to <span style={{color:"#6246EA"}}>+911234567890</span></p>
          </div>
        
          <Form>
              <FormGroup>
                <FormLabel>Type your 6-digit OTP here</FormLabel>
                <FormControl type="number" name="otp" required/>
                
                <div className="text-center pt-2">
                  <p className="text-Muted">I didn’t receive a code. <span style={{color:"#6246EA"}}>Resend Code    </span> </p>
                </div>
              </FormGroup>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const Step5 =()=>{
    return (
      <div className="Registration_Form">
        <div className="text-center pb-4">
          <h3>Tell Us About Yourself</h3>
        </div>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">

          <Form.Label>Enter Your First name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="text" placeholder="First name" name="firstname"/>

          <Form.Label>Enter Your Middle name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="text" placeholder="Middle name" name="middlename"/>

          <Form.Label>Enter Your last name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="lastname"/>

          <Form.Label>Date Of Birth</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="date" name="dob"/>

          <Form.Label>Occupation</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="text" placeholder="What is your Occupation.." name="occupation" />

          </Form.Group>
        </Form>  
      </div>   
    )
  }

  const Step6 =()=>{
    return (
      <div className="Registration_Form">
        <div className="text-center pb-2">
          <h3>Tell Us About Yourself</h3>
        </div>
        <Form>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3">

            <Form.Label>Country Of Residance</Form.Label>
            <Form.Select className="mb-2" name="resCountry">
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="United State">United State</option>
            </Form.Select>

            <Form.Label>Home address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Address..." name="homeaddress"/>

            <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your City..." name="city"/>

            <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your State..." name="state" />

            <Form.Label>Postal Code</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control className="mb-2" type="number" placeholder='Enter Your Postal Code...' name="postalcode" />

            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
      </div>   
    )
  }

  const Step7 =()=>{
    return (
      <div className="Registration_Form">
      <div className='text-center'>
      <h4 style={{fontWeight:"700",lineHeight:"1.4"}}>Setup login details For Your <span style={{color:'#6246EA'}}>ViniPay</span> Account</h4>
      <p>It will help you to log back into your account.</p>
  </div>
  <Form>
      <FormGroup>
          <Form.Label>Create Username</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control className='UserLoginPwd' type="text" placeholder="Enter Username ..." />
          <div>
          {['warning'].map((variant) => (
              <Alert key={variant} variant={variant}>
                  This Username is alredy in use. try something different!
              </Alert>
            ))}
          </div>

          <Form.Label>Create Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control  className='UserLoginPwd' type="password" placeholder="Create Password ..."/>
          
          <div>
          {['info'].map((variant) => (
              <Alert key={variant} variant={variant}>
              Password (Must be 8 characters and include one uppercase, one lowercase ,one numeric and one special symbol) 
              </Alert>
            ))}
          </div>

          <Form.Label>Confirm Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control className='UserLoginPwd' type="password" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password ..." />

          <div>
          {['danger'].map((variant) => (
              <Alert key={variant} variant={variant}>
                  Password and confirm password does not match. 
              </Alert>
            ))}
          </div>
      </FormGroup>

  </Form>
      </div>
    )
  }

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: "",
    country: "",
    countryCode: "",
    phone: "",
    otp:"",
    firstname: "",
    middlename:"",
    lastname:"",
    dob:"",
    occupation:"",
    resCountry:"",
    homeaddress:"",
    city:"",
    state:"",
    postalcode:"",

  });

  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  const history = useHistory()

  const nextStep = () => {
    if (step < 7) {
      setStep(step + 1);
    } else if(step === 7) {
        console.log(values);
        history.push("./routes/signup")

    }
  };

  const prevStep = () => {
    if (step > 1) {
      setStep(step - 1);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (name) => (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: e.target.values });
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/signup', handleChange)
      .then(response => console.log(response.data))

    window.location = "../Login"

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar/>
      <div>
        {
          {
            1: <Step1 />,
            2: <Step2 />,
            3: <Step3 />,
            4: <Step4 />,
            5: <Step5 />,
            6: <Step6 />,
            7: <Step7 />,
          }[step]
        }
      </div>
    
        <div>
        <div className=" mt-0 pt-0 Registration_Form_Butttons">
              {step > 1 ? (
                <button className="buttn-dark inlinebtn" onClick={prevStep}>
                  Back
                </button>
              ) : null}
           
            <button className="buttn-dark inlinebtn" onClick={nextStep}>
              {step === 7 ? "Submit" : "Continue"}
              console.log(values)
            </button>

              {step === 1 ? <p style={{fontWeight:"600",fontSize:"18px"}} className="pt-4">Already have an account? <Link style={{textDecoration:"none", color:"#6246EA"}} to="./Login">Log in</Link></p> : <p></p>}
        </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: In your Steps, you don't store the data or you are storing it in the local state. Instead, you want to pass the callback handler from the parent to each step, so it can update the parent state rather than its own

Comment: can you please help me with a little more detail. I'm new to nodejs

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with nodejs. It's your front end that doesn't send the correct data to you back end. You would need to lift the state from your children to the parent. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html
Also, I just noticed that to your axios request, you are passing a reference to your handleChange function. I think you need to send your values rather than the function